# How to create a class to serialize recreation.gov campsite json data in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I am trying to use the recreations.gov api to find available campsites. When I receive the data I am not sure how to serialize it. Can someone help me create the correct class structure? I removed some of the availability and quantity entries. One for each day of the month is returned.

Thanks,
Jeremiah

```
{
  "campsites": {
    "1": {
      "availabilities": {
        "2023-08-01T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
        "2023-08-0T00:00:00Z": "Reserved"
      },
      "campsite_id": "1",
      "campsite_reserve_type": "Site-Specific",
      "campsite_rules": null,
      "campsite_type": "RV NONELECTRIC",
      "capacity_rating": "Single",
      "loop": "C ",
      "max_num_people": 6,
      "min_num_people": 0,
      "quantities": {
        "2023-08-01T00:00:00Z": 0,
        "2023-08-31T00:00:00Z": 0
      },
      "site": "065",
      "supplemental_camping": null,
      "type_of_use": "Overnight"
    },
    "2": {
      "availabilities": {
        "2023-08-01T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
        "2023-08-31T00:00:00Z": "Reserved"
      },
      "campsite_id": "2",
      "campsite_reserve_type": "Site-Specific",
      "campsite_rules": null,
      "campsite_type": "RV NONELECTRIC",
      "capacity_rating": "Single",
      "loop": "C",
      "max_num_people": 6,
      "min_num_people": 0,
      "quantities": {
        "2023-08-01T00:00:00Z": 0,
        "2023-08-31T00:00:00Z": 0
      },
      "site": "066",
      "supplemental_camping": null,
      "type_of_use": "Overnight"
    }
  },
  "count": 99
}
```

I have read tons of post about json serialization and tried creating the class with https://jsonutils.com/ but the values become properties of the class which doesn't make sense. I am wondering if the json they return is invalid.

```
   Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property campsites As Campsites
        Public Property count As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Campsites
        Public Property _1 As _1
        Public Property _2 As _2
    End Class

    Public Class _1
        Public Property availabilities As Availabilities
        Public Property campsite_id As String
        Public Property campsite_reserve_type As String
        Public Property campsite_rules As Object
        Public Property campsite_type As String
        Public Property capacity_rating As String
        Public Property _loop As String
        Public Property max_num_people As Integer
        Public Property min_num_people As Integer
        Public Property quantities As Quantities
        Public Property site As String
        Public Property supplemental_camping As Object
        Public Property type_of_use As String
    End Class

    Public Class Availabilities
        Public Property _20230801T000000Z As String
        Public Property _2023080T000000Z As String
    End Class

    Public Class Quantities
        Public Property _20230801T000000Z As Integer
        Public Property _20230831T000000Z As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class _2
        Public Property availabilities As Availabilities1
        Public Property campsite_id As String
        Public Property campsite_reserve_type As String
        Public Property campsite_rules As Object
        Public Property campsite_type As String
        Public Property capacity_rating As String
        Public Property _loop As String
        Public Property max_num_people As Integer
        Public Property min_num_people As Integer
        Public Property quantities As Quantities1
        Public Property site As String
        Public Property supplemental_camping As Object
        Public Property type_of_use As String
    End Class

    Public Class Availabilities1
        Public Property _20230801T000000Z As String
        Public Property _20230831T000000Z As String
    End Class

    Public Class Quantities1
        Public Property _20230801T000000Z As Integer
        Public Property _20230831T000000Z As Integer
    End Class
```

Comment: The availabilities and quatities json does indeed look strange. Probably worth contacting them to discuss.

Comment: I have been using this as a guide and it seems to process it fine. 
https://github.com/banool/recreation-gov-campsite-checker/blob/master/camping.py

Comment: The following may be helpful: [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will get you there with a bit of manual effort.

The json class:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class CampSiteProcessor

    Public Class RecreationSite

        Public Sub New()
            CampSiteLists = New List(Of Campsite)
        End Sub
        Public Property CampSiteLists As List(Of Campsite)
        Public Property campsites As String
        Public Property count As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Campsite

        Public Sub New()
            AvailObjects = New List(Of AvailObject)
            QuantityObjects = New List(Of QuantityObject)
        End Sub
        Public Property AvailObjects As IList(Of AvailObject)
        Public Property campsite_id As String
        Public Property campsite_reserve_type As String
        Public Property campsite_rules As Object
        Public Property campsite_type As String
        Public Property capacity_rating As String

        <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="loop")>
        Public Property _loop As String
        Public Property max_num_people As Integer
        Public Property min_num_people As Integer
        Public Property QuantityObjects As IList(Of QuantityObject)
        Public Property site As String
        Public Property supplemental_camping As Object
        Public Property type_of_use As String
    End Class

    Public Class AvailObject
        Public Property DateValue As String
        Public Property StringValue As String
    End Class

    Public Class QuantityObject
        Public Property DateValue As String
        Public Property AmountValue As String
    End Class

End Class
```

A method to parse the incoming json and leave you with a collection of campsites:

```
    Private Sub ParseCampSites(jsonString As String)

        Dim token As JToken = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
        ' find the campsites collection
        Dim campsitesjson = token.SelectToken("campsites")
        Dim recSite As New RecreationSite

        Dim campcounter As Integer = 0

        ' loop through the collection
        For Each obj In campsitesjson

            campcounter += 1
            ' find the specific campsite
            Dim campSiteToken = token.SelectToken($"campsites.{campcounter}")
            Dim campSiteItem As Campsite = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Campsite)(campSiteToken.ToString)

            ' find the availabilities list
            Dim availabilities = token.SelectToken($"campsites.{campcounter}.availabilities")
            For Each item As Object In availabilities
                Dim dateValue As String = item.name
                Dim statusValue As String = item.value
                campSiteItem.AvailObjects.Add(New AvailObject With {.DateValue = dateValue, .StringValue = statusValue})
            Next

            ' find the quantities list
            Dim quantities = token.SelectToken($"campsites.{campcounter}.quantities")
            For Each item As Object In quantities
                Dim dateValue As String = item.name
                Dim amountValue As String = item.value
                campSiteItem.QuantityObjects.Add(New QuantityObject With {.DateValue = dateValue, .AmountValue = amountValue})
            Next
            ' add campsite to collection
            recSite.CampSiteLists.Add(campSiteItem)

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write that for me! I was lost and couldn't figure it out. This helped me get my software working.